# Series expansion of $\ln(\sec x + \tan x)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm looking for series expansion of  $\ln(\sec x + \tan x)$ ?
I tried to differentiate and then find an expansion then integrating but found nothing.

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=21180

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I know that an expansion is available for $\sec x$ but how to use it?

Comment: then why don't you integrate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(\sec x+\tan x)=\frac{\sec x\tan x+\sec^2x}{\sec x+\tan x}=\sec x=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^nE_{2n}}{(2n)!}x^{2n}\;,$$

where $E_{2n}$ is an [Euler number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number), the coefficient of $\dfrac{t^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ in the Maclaurin series expansion of $\dfrac1{\cosh t}$. This is easy enough to integrate termwise, though of course the resulting series will still have Euler numbers in the coefficients.

Comment: I was making a funny mistake that made me not to get to this :D

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is perfectly fine. First notice that
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\log(\sec x + \tan x) = \sec x $$
Then we use the series expansion of $ \sec x $ (which you can get using a number of different methods) yields
$$ \sec x = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{5x^4}{24} + O(x^6) $$
Finally you integrate the above to get the desired result.